# Understanding circuit to Hamiltonian embedding where we do not have a separate clock register

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, adiabatic-model, hamiltonian, embedding

I am trying to understand the clock construction given in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4077) paper, to embed a circuit to a Hamiltonian, which doesn't need to access a separate clock register.

The construction, at a high level, comprises of using a complicated sequence of flag qubits and other machinery to "guide" the computation across the 1D line. I am very confused about how the computation is being guided. As a reference, this diagram is provided (Figure $1$):

[image]

I am very confused about whether the gates we are applying are one or two qubit gates and how exactly we are apply these gates. I am also confused about why the computation after going from left to right, suddenly "turns" back (from steps $4$ onwards).

If someone could provide a detailed explanation of the entire construction, that would be very helpful!

Comment: I like many of Irani's lectures and presentations about these - see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8o_M8twaOs) e.g., but I'll be honest, after a bit most  of these proofs look to me like a clever way to recast the Cook-Levin proof into different quantum contexts.  I'd try to grok her lecture on Kitaev's initial QMA proof if I were you...